# Global menu not working in 13.10

Tags: google-chrome, 13.10, gnome-terminal, appmenu, globalmenu

After upgrading to 13.10 the global menu doesn't show for some applications like Terminal and Chrome.

Is this a bug or is it normal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same issue. And this is a bug and it's reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221304

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem I was able to fix by installing `unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk3-module`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk3-module
```

Just to quote what I've already said on launchpad

> On side note why this has happened to me is cause of this bug during the upgrade:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1241563
>
> Which broke my upgrade progress, I was only able to continue it with `sudo apt-get install -f` which most likefly failed to install new packages as it didn't know about them

Comment: I have those packages installed so that's not the answer for me...

Comment: @Dan Not working for me, it's not an update error. But if that fixed it for you, that means you are currently using Chrome on 13.10 and global menus are working?
Which exact version of Chrome are you using?
Which update sources do you have enabled (security/updates/proposed/backports)?

Comment: @Donarsson Somehow I missed the word "Chrome" in the question. No, I don't have a global menu in chrome, but I'm not sure if Chrome has one. Though, I had problems in the Terminal and the USC and a few other apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bug:

See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306667

Star the issue to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was on the Chrome team's end, and has been fixed in newer versions, with multiple reports of it working on 13.10 and 14.04.

**Update to Chrome 35**, and it should be resolved. Since it's currently in Beta, either change your channel; or just wait it out. Don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score -3):

ansidev, are you even aware of the what the global menu is, or even what gnome is as of now? To answer the question, it is perfectly normal for Google Chrome to not have global menu integration. It's plain and simple- not supported. Firefox has global menu integration, BTW! As for the terminal, are you using the default gnome terminal or something else? Global menu integration depends from application to application. So rest assured, it's not a bug.

Comment: Please use the comment feature to reply to answers.
Also, Chrome **does** support global menus, they work just fine on 13.04 and other Linux distros.

Comment: Donarsson is right. Chrome worked fine in 13.04. And i'm using the default Gnome terminal, which should be supported.